# Как устранить зависание сокета?

Tags: python, micropython, esp32

Написал код для получения информации от esp32 через сокет. Пока соединение стабильное (wi-fi), информация поступает и все ок. Даже после прерывания скрипта-клиента через ctrl+c повторное подключение проходит нормально. Но если по каким-то причинам пропадет связь между десктопом и esp-шкой, то сокет "зависает" и подключиться к мк не получается. Я пока еще только начинаю пробовать писать такие скрипты и не понимаю, где искать ошибки, может вообще весь подход неверный. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так.

Скрипт на esp32:

```
import socket
from machine import Pin
import onewire
import ds18x20

ds_sensor = ds18x20.DS18X20(onewire.OneWire(Pin(4)))
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind(('192.168.1.101', 9000))
server_socket.settimeout(10)
server_socket.listen(20)

while True:
    client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()

    while True:
        request = client_socket.recv(4096)

        if not request:
            break
        else:
            temp = "0"
            roms = ds_sensor.scan()
            ds_sensor.convert_temp()
            for rom in roms:
               temp = ds_sensor.read_temp(rom)
            response = str(temp).encode()
            client_socket.send(response)
```

Скрипт-клиент:

```
import socket
import time

host = "192.168.1.101"
port = 9000

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect((host, port))

while True:
    sock.send(bytes(1))
    data = sock.recv(4096)
    param_list = data.decode()
    print(param_list)
    time.sleep(1)
```